# Difference between ftp and uploading file by using input/output streams

Tags: java, file, file-upload

I am trying to write a file uploader in java. It's requirements are to get the file from a user and save the file on the server. This file should be later downlaod-able.

I came across this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glraq.html) from java which simply reads the contents of the file as input stream and write it at the specified location on the server to a new file as output stream.

1) My question is, what is this method of file uploading/transferring called?

2) How is it different from the FTP protocol?

Comment: Your link is broken

Comment: @Digital-Thinking I just checked it again and it works for me. What do you get when you try to access it?

Comment: Works now, was a 404 before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's HTTP upload, using Java EE and a servlet to handle the receiving of the file.

It's a different protocol. FTP requires an FTP server and HTTP file upload requires a HTTP server with something on the backend to handle the data coming in.

Comment: Going in a bit more detail, what would be the basic difference between a FTP server and a HTTP server?

Comment: One is a server for the File Transfer Protocol, the other is a server for HyperText Transfer Protocol. There's quite a lot of differences, what they have in common is they're both protocols (usually working on top of TCP/IP).

Comment: How could you see that its an http upload? I mean how can i look at that code and figure out the same?

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to look at the code and the classes being used. Basic reading and understanding of code is required.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific please? For my part, the only hint i see is that its making a http post and than using a HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse objects.

Comment: I don't really know how to be more specific. There are multiple libraries you can use that handle things for you, or you can do it yourself with a standard `POST` request. What other "hints" do you think there would be?